# How can I give a user that can not log into a RHEL server the ability to start / stop applications or reboot server?

Tags: ssh, rhel

We are building a secure platform so that only a few people have rights to ssh into the servers, but I still need the ability for support personnel to be able to start or stop applications and if needed reboot the server all without being able to ssh into the server.

Comment: A couple of possible options (a) build a web console that provides a service control UI; (b) allow them to ssh into the server but into a restricted environment that only permits starting/stopping services.

Answer (score 2):

If the actual requirement is that the support personnel must not be able to **access the command line**, then you could write a script that displays a fixed menu of actions allowed for the support personnel, and then use the `chsh` command to *set that script as the login shell for the support personnel accounts*.

If you want to be extra sure, you might build a dedicated binary executable that will present the menu, and use that as the login shell instead of a script. But using a script might be easier at the prototyping stage.

When a menu script/binary is used as user's login shell, there will be no shell accessible by interrupting the menu script/binary: if the menu script/binary dies *for any reason*, the session will immediately end as the system considers it a logout.

When done this way, the menu will be displayed any time the support account logs in, both for local and SSH logins. Attempts to escape the menu will just cause the session to terminate.

---

Alternatively, `sshd`'s `authorized_keys` file can be used to define *forced commands*: when a SSH session is initiated with key authentication and the key in question has a forced command associated with it, `sshd` will run **only the specified command** and once it ends, the session will terminate.

Basically, you could create a SSH key pair for user `support` (with e.g. `ssh-keygen -f rebootkey_ed25519 -t ed25519`, place its public key (the contents of `rebootkey_ed25519.pub`) to `~support/.ssh/authorized_keys` prefixed with `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot"`, so that the `authorized_keys` line for the key will look like this:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot" ssh-ed25519 <public_key_alphabet_soup_here> [optional comment]
```

Then use `visudo` to configure `/etc/sudoers` to allow the user `support` to run `/sbin/reboot`, either with or without a password prompt:

```
support ALL=(root) /sbin/reboot
```

or

```
support ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

Then you could give the private key file `rebootkey_ed25519` to the support personnel, and instruct them to run `ssh -i rebootkey_ed25519 support@hostname_or_ip` when the server needs to be rebooted.

Now, when the `rebootkey_ed25519` private key is used to login as user `support`, the `sshd` will ignore any remote commands specified on the `ssh` command line, and will run `sudo reboot` as the `support` user. Depending on which version of the `sudo` configuration used, `sudo` may or may not require the password of the `support` user too. Once the `sudo reboot` command terminates for any reason, the SSH session will end.

You can define multiple SSH keys with specific commands, with an unique SSH key for each command to run.

---

If the support personnel must not use SSH at all, then you could set up a web server with an ability to run CGI scripts, write a script for each action you wish the support personnel to be able to do (using `sudo` with `NOPASSWD:` as appropriate to authorize the user used to run the CGI scripts to run the necessary commands as root), and write a simple web page with a menu of actions as links to the appropriate scripts.

If you do this, you definitely should restrict access to that webpage by IP addresses and/or require authentication+HTTPS.